# Rename keys with ramda js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```
const orignalArr = [
  {
    personName: 'Joe'
  }
]
```

expected output:

```
const convertedArr = [
  {
    name: 'Joe'
  }
]
```

I'm thinking the renamed keys are defined in an object (but fine if there's a better way to map them):

```
const keymaps = {
  personName: 'name'
};
```

How can I do this with Ramda?

Something with `R.map`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is [an entry](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#rename-keys-of-an-object) in [Ramda's Cookbook](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook) for this:

```js
const renameKeys = R.curry((keysMap, obj) =>
  R.reduce((acc, key) => R.assoc(keysMap[key] || key, obj[key], acc), {}, R.keys(obj))
);

const originalArr = [{personName: 'Joe'}]

console .log (
  R.map (renameKeys ({personName: 'name'}), originalArr)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

But with the  ubiquity of ES6, it's pretty easy to write this directly:

```js
const renameKeys = (keysMap) => (obj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce(
  (a, [k, v]) => k in keysMap ? {...a, [keysMap[k]]: v} : {...a, [k]: v},
  {}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine Ramda with [Ramda Adjunct](https://char0n.github.io/ramda-adjunct/2.27.0/index.html). Using the `renameKeys` (https://char0n.github.io/ramda-adjunct/2.27.0/RA.html#.renameKeys) method is very useful. With it you can simply do something like this:

```js
const people = [
  {
    personName: 'Joe'
  }
]

const renameKeys = R.map(RA.renameKeys({ personName: 'name' }));

const __people__ = renameKeys(people);

console.log(__people__) // [ { name: 'Joe' }]
```

Hope it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my take on `renameKeys`. The main idea is to separate the keys and values to two array. Map the array of keys, and replace with values from `keyMap` (if exist), then zip back to object:

```js
const { pipe, toPairs, transpose, converge, zipObj, head, map, last } = R

const renameKeys = keysMap => pipe(
  toPairs, // convert to entries
  transpose, // convert to array of keys, and array of values
  converge(zipObj, [ // zip back to object
    pipe(head, map(key => keysMap[key] || key)), // rename the keys
    last // get the values
  ])
)
  


const originalArr = [{ personName: 'Joe', lastName: 'greg' }]

const result = R.map(renameKeys({ personName: 'name' }), originalArr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea to make it is to first check that the old prop I want to rename exists, and the new key I want to create doesn’t.

Then, I will use the `S_` common combinator to make it point-free.

Find JS common combinators [here](https://gist.github.com/Avaq/1f0636ec5c8d6aed2e45)

```js
const { 
    allPass, assoc, compose: B, complement, has, omit, prop, when
} = require('ramda');

const S_ = (f) => (g) => (x) => f (g (x)) (x);

const renameKey = (newKey) => (oldKey) => when(allPass([
    has(oldKey)
    , complement(has)(newKey)
]))
(B(omit([oldKey]), S_(assoc(newKey))(prop(oldKey))))
    
const obj = { fullname: 'Jon' };

renameKey('name')('fullname')(obj) // => { name: ‘Jon’ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution, not too many arrow functions (just one), mostly pure Ramda calls. And it is one of shortest, if not the shortest ;)

First, based on your example

```
const { apply, compose, either, flip, identity, map, mergeAll, objOf, prop, replace, toPairs, useWith } = require('ramda');             

const RenameKeys = f => compose(mergeAll, map(apply(useWith(objOf, [f]))), toPairs);

const originalArr = [
    {
        personName: 'Joe',
    },
];

const keymaps = {
    personName: 'name',
};

// const HowToRename = flip(prop)(keymaps); // if you don't have keys not specified in keymaps explicitly
const HowToRename = either(flip(prop)(keymaps), identity);

console.log(map(RenameKeys(HowToRename))(originalArr));
```

Second option, using any arbitrary lambda with renaming rules:

```
const { apply, compose, map, mergeAll, objOf, replace, toPairs, useWith } = require('ramda');

const RenameKeys = f => compose(mergeAll, map(apply(useWith(objOf, [f]))), toPairs);

const HowToRename = replace(/(?<=.)(?!$)/g, '_'); // for example

console.log(RenameKeys(HowToRename)({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }));
```

Yields

> { o_n_e: 1, t_w_o: 2, t_h_r_e_e: 3 }

Third, you can use object-based rename rules from the first example and use fallback strategy, e.g. `replace` like in the second example, instead of `identity`.